# In Python, printing a newline when a word is in line

Tags: python, string, file, newline

I wanna print a '\n' to separate the lines when a specific word is found. This is what i did:

```
with open('test.txt') as my_file:
   match = False
   for line in my_file:
       if 'location'  in line:
           print('\n')
       if 'text1' in line:
           match = True
       elif 'text3' in line:
           match = False
       elif match:
            print(" ".join(line.split()))
```

But this prints before the word 'location'. For example:

```
text1

location
text2
```

I want it to print as such:

```
text1
location

text2
```

Comment: Put the print after?

Comment: You never print the line, so you're only going to get newlines.

Comment: please, post the full code

Comment: I've edited the post..

Comment: Print the new line *after* printing the line itself.  Also, what's the intention behind the `match` variable ? It will cause all lines following `test1` to be skipped up to the next line following `test3`. Is that intentional ? Is it relevant to your question ?

Comment: @AlainT. the match is used to find the pattern in my file. When the match is true, it's gonna print the lines in between until match is false. The reason I want to print newline is to act as a separator between those lines but not all lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('test.txt') as my_file:
   for line in my_file:
       print(line)
       if 'location'  in line:
           print('\n')
```